# Is there is a way to apply automatic coupon code in Magento 2 if total is greater than 1000?

Tags: magento2, cart, discount, coupon-codes

I have a Magento 2.4 Store in which i want to **auto apply coupon code**  when the total of the product is greater than 1000.

Like i don't want to enter that in discount box
[image]

Like here i don't want to enter here it will be auto apply when subtotal is greater than 1000.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Added the screenshot of my cart rule please verify if there is any issue as it will not apply discount on checkout page.**

Thanks

==================================================================

[image]

Comment: In above case you can create `Cart Price Rule`.They will automatically apply based on condition!

Comment: Thanks for your response @Pawan I have created cart rule but it doesn't apply cart rule.I have added screenshot for cart rule please check if i have done something wrong.

Comment: did you check cart rule after the re indexing ?

Comment: @Prits, Your rule seems correct.Just check other cart rule not stopping this new rule.

Comment: @Singhe thanks its working.

Comment: @pawan thanks its working.

Answer (score 4):

You can just create a cart price rule that does not have a coupon code and it's valid for orders over 1000. It will not apply a coupon code (because there is none) but the user will see in the checkout the discount applied.

Comment: Thanks for your response @marius I have created cart rule but it doesn't apply cart rule on checkout page .I have added screenshot for my cart rule please check if i have done something wrong please check.

Answer (score 0):

You should click on "is" and then select "greater than" in the dropdown menu. Than just enter the amount you want in your case "1000".